# Ensure only one tag is supplied by user in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have written a playbook which behave differently with the tags supplied to the playbook. I have ensured that user is providing at least on tag to the playbook while running it. However, I need to ensure that user is only providing ONLY ONE tag to the playbook. Is it possible to do ? I have searched over internet but results are negative.

```
-->cat foo.yml

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Check user inputs
      fail: msg="ERROR:User must use ONE TAG"

    - name: print message A
      debug:
        msg: "This is message A"
      tags:
         - printA

    - name: print message B
      debug:
        msg: "This is message B"
      tags:
         - printB
```

Working: When one tag is provided ,should work.

```
ansible-playbook -i localhost foo.yml --tags="printA"
ansible-playbook -i localhost foo.yml --tags="printB"
```

Working: When no tag is provided, Fail and exit

```
ansible-playbook -i localhost foo.yml
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ERROR:User must use ONE TAG"}
```

Not sure how to do this: where more then one tag is provided.Fail and exit

```
ansible-playbook -i localhost foo.yml --tags="printB, printA"
```

Update:

Here is updated PB from @ilias-sp answer:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  tasks:
    - name: Check how many tags were provided
      fail:
        msg: "0 or more than 1 tags were provided. Exiting.."
      failed_when: hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags']|length > 1 or
                   (hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags']|length == 1 and hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags'][0] == 'all')
      tags:
         - always
    - name: print message A
      debug:
        msg: "This is message A"
      tags:
         - printA

    - name: print message B
      debug:
        msg: "This is message B"
      tags:
         - printB
```

## results:

```
ansible-playbook foo.yml --tags="printA, printB"  # failing
ansible-playbook foo.yml --tags="printA"          #failing
ansible-playbook foo.yml                          #failing
```

## Error:

```
TASK [Check how many tags were provided] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags']|length > 1 or (hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags']|length == 1 and hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags'][0] == 'all')' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags']|length > 1 or (hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags']|length == 1 and hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags'][0] == 'all')): 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_run_tags'"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `fail` module task as a check for tags in your PB, it will fail the PB when you have 0 or more than 1 tags provided:

```
  - name: Check how many tags were provided
    fail:
      msg: "0 or more than 1 tags were provided. Exiting.."
    failed_when: hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags']|length > 1 or
                 (hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags']|length == 1 and hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags'][0] == 'all')
    tags:
    - always
```

i tested with:

- 0 tags (in this case the `ansible_run_tags` has 1 element: `all`)
- 1 tag
- more than 1 tags

and it worked as expected. hope it helps

### UPDATE

sample PB and execution runs:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:

  tasks:
  - name: Check how many tags were provided
    fail:
      msg: "0 or more than 1 tags were provided. Exiting.."
    failed_when: hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags']|length > 1 or
                 (hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags']|length == 1 and hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags'][0] == 'all')
    tags:
    - always

  - name: print results
    debug:
      var: hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags']
    tags:
    - always
```

3 runs:

```
[http_offline@greenhat-29 tests]$ ansible-playbook test.yml

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Check how many tags were provided] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed_when_result": true, "msg": "0 or more than 1 tags were provided. Exiting.."}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1   

[http_offline@greenhat-29 tests]$ ansible-playbook test.yml --tags="printA"

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Check how many tags were provided] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [print results] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "hostvars['localhost']['ansible_run_tags']": [
        "printA"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   

[http_offline@greenhat-29 tests]$ ansible-playbook test.yml --tags="printA, printB"

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Check how many tags were provided] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed_when_result": true, "msg": "0 or more than 1 tags were provided. Exiting.."}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1   

[http_offline@greenhat-29 tests]$
```

### UPDATE no2:

This solution will work with Ansible 2.7.X. Older versions like 2.4.X would need another approach - if any

Comment: thank you, it is failing for `ansible-playbook -i localhost foo.yml --tags="printA" Its a single tag, so this should work
`

Comment: thats weird, it works OK for me. i added sample PB and 3 runs (no tags, 1 tag, 2 tags)

Comment: please check the update in the question, I have added the updated PB from your answer and error message

Comment: looks like you dont have the `ansible_run_tags` variable in your `hostvars`. what ansible version you are using? i am on 2.7.7. My suggestion would be to dump the `hostvars` and find out where ansible keeps your tags, then update the task accordingly.

Comment: I am using `ansible-playbook 2.4.2.0`

Comment: `grep tag` is empty. for this version.

Comment: you are right...  i found 2.4.6 ansible, and the hostvars don't contain any information on the tags supplied. so this approach wont work for you. since this enhancement is needed for you, why dont you consider upgrading ansible on your environment? you are using a version which is older than `2018-07-11` ..

Comment: no problem at all, had the opportunity to learn a couple of things about tags today! cheers :)